# Doing Date Conversion

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am not that that strong at doing date conversions.  I am sure I am loosing records because of time stamp.  I need to convert my date in this query so i can get a rolling Quarter to date sum.  Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
SELECT   
     a.UserID_Caller ,a.csCallType,timewait,a.convotime,datename(quarter,timewait)as qrt,datename(year,timewait)as yr,datename(month,timewait)as mnth,datename(day,timewait)as dy
        --sum(case when datename(year,timewait) = (datename(year,getdate()-1)) AND (datename(Quarter,timewait))=(datename(Quarter,getdate()-1)) and (datename(day,timewait))<>(datename(day,getdate()))then (a.convotime)/60 else 0 end) as [MTD]
FROM  satVRS.dbo.rptNECACallHistory as a
WHERE 
        a.IsReport = 1 
    -AND (datename(year,timewait))=(datename(year,getdate()-1)) AND (datename(quarter,timewait))=(datename(quarter,getdate()-1))  and (datename(day,timewait))<>(datename(day,getdate()))
     and month(timewait)     
    AND a.convotime > 0
    AND a.NECA_isReport = 1        
    AND a.Video in ('SV')

GROUP BY a.UserID_Caller ,a.csCallType,timewait,a.convotime
order by timewait,a.UserID_Caller
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data to illustrate what you mean by rolling quarter to date?

Comment: Here is some sample data I will be suming convotime to obtain a daily total, MTD, QTD, and YTD

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking to query a list of calls as MTD, QTD and YTD

I noticed that you are subtracting 1 from getdate()...
  Usually when you are looking for MTD, QTD or YTD it would be in relation to the current Month Quarter or Year. and in all cases would be to the current year. So for example if you are looking for MTD for 1/1/2014 this would only include calls for 1/1 in the year 2014. If you were looking for QTD for 3/1/2014 it would include 1/1 - 3/1 in the year 2014, as you can see this is not 3 months prior to current date. Finally if you were looking for YTD for 10/1/2014 you would be looking for all calls in the year 2014.

so for MTD your WHERE clause would look like ...

```
where 
    month(datefield) = month(getdate())
    and year(datefield) = year(getdate())
```

for QTD your WHERE clause would look like ...

```
where
    datename(QUARTER,datefield) = datename(QUARTER,getdate()
    and year(datefield) = year(getdate())
```

and finally for YTD your WHERE clause would look like ...

```
where
   year(datefield) = year(getdate())
```

I hope that helps.